# DAX studio showing additional (duplicate) local tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

My power Bi model contains the following tables:

[image]

However, when I connect to this model from DAX studio, I get the following:
[image]

Please note that all of these local date tables show the same metadata like the date table. Is this a potential problem? I believe this might be the reason behind this report working comparatively slow while development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tables show date tables automatically created by Power BI for all fields type "Date", to enable date hierarchy for them (year/quarter/month/day).

If you want to remove them, go to File/Options, then under "Current File"  uncheck "Auto Date/Time":

[image]

These hidden tables will disappear. If you want to turn this feature off for all future/new  files (I always do), uncheck a similar option under "Global".